# How to train several different regression models according to some criteria in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I plotted a rolling correlation graph of my data and found out that the correlation of some of my dependent variables and target variable change from highly positive to negative for a small period of time then getting back to normal. What I want to do is to drop these variables at that specific time period from my linear regression model and adding them back when their correlation back to normal.

So I think that would equal to training several different models and combine them afterwards.
Does anyone have any idea how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is clean the data, rather than creating a model for each different behavior.

Here's a full sklearn tutorial on data preprocessing that you might find helpful:

- http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html

So, the overall process in your case would be:

1. **outlier detection:** detect the part of the data which has an abnormal behavior
2. **data imputation:** You can replace the variables values in abnormal period with the mean of each variable values outside of the abnormal period.
3. **Training:**  train your model on the cleaned data.

Comment: Thank you but in my case, the abnormal behavior is not caused by the outlier value of the data. My data set is about a stock price which is a time series and very hard to explain why there is a sudden flip of the correaltion. Maybe it's not even caused by the number itself but caused by some special news or event. But if I include this abnormal correlation in the model, it won't perform well right?

Comment: @Dylan it depends of the model, but in general, machine learning algorithms are learning to average the effect of all observations included in the dataset to learn the right parameters for a given model so yes, the abnormal observations will affect your model.